# ignoring session_start() & getallheaders() error Opencart

Tags: php, json, rest, opencart, fpm

I'm running RestAPI on Opencart 1.5.2.1, the server runs PHP Version 7.1.19 and Server API FPM/FastCGI over Apache. I'm facing issues with session, I have a VQMOD xml file installed to add certain functions to the system session of Opencart.

Please let me share the whole session code first:

```
  <file name="system/library/session.php">
   <operation>
      <search  position="before"><![CDATA[
          if (!session_id()) {
      ]]></search>
      <add><![CDATA[
          $token_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

          if (isset($token_array['ic_token'])) {
          $ic_token = $token_array['ic_token'];
          } elseif(isset($_POST['ic_token'])){
          $ic_token = $_POST['ic_token'];
          }

          if (isset(getallheaders()['ic_token'])) {
          $ic_token = getallheaders()['ic_token'];
          } elseif (isset(getallheaders()['Ic-Token'])) {
          $ic_token = getallheaders()['Ic-Token'];
          }

          if (isset($ic_token) && $ic_token != 'Session_Not_Loggin') {
          session_id($ic_token);
          session_start();
          }
      ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

When calling a function using Postman I first get an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   getallheaders() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_session.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/admin/index.php(110):
>   Session->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_session.php
>   on line 15

I googled and found that PHP-FPM doesn't support getallheaders() I tried a workaround but didn't work. I've removed the code from the xml code and became like that:

```
      <file name="system/library/session.php">
       <operation>
          <search  position="before"><![CDATA[
              if (!session_id()) {
          ]]></search>
          <add><![CDATA[
              $token_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

              if (isset($token_array['ic_token'])) {
              $ic_token = $token_array['ic_token'];
              } elseif(isset($_POST['ic_token'])){
              $ic_token = $_POST['ic_token'];
              }

==> the getallheaders() code has been removed



              if (isset($ic_token) && $ic_token != 'Session_Not_Loggin') {
              session_id($ic_token);
              session_start();
              }
          ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

This has caused a new error:

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_session.php
>   on line 19

Please not I tried this workaround

```
          if (!function_exists('getallheaders'))
          {
            function getallheaders()
            {
              if (isset(getallheaders()['ic_token'])) {
              $ic_token = getallheaders()['ic_token'];
              } elseif (isset(getallheaders()['Ic-Token'])) {
              $ic_token = getallheaders()['Ic-Token'];
              };
            };
           };
```

This is giving me 503 Service Unavailable "Unexpected '<'"

Any help please, highly appreciated.